# I am going to get dress

Tags: grammar

I told my son we were going to shopping.

> "I am going to get dress."
>
> "I am going to getting dress."

Is getting dress a noun? I know after "to" must be present tense.
It should be get or getting?

Comment: Do you mean that you're about to put your clothes on?  (If so, "I'm going to get dressed.")  Or do you mean that you're going to buy a dress when you reach the shops?  (If so, "I'm going to get **a** dress", "I'm going to buy a dress", "I'm going to look for a dress", or "I'm getting a dress".)

Comment: No. I'm going to change my shirt (home) to another shirt (shopping). @rjpond

Comment: Please edit your question to include your clarification.  Thanks.